# ExtJS 4.2.1 resetting Stores on ViewChange

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-stores

in my ExtJS application I want to reset the stores when I change the page. 
Which means I don't want any filters, groupings or listener from any old view/page.

Currentyl I am setting the store of my view like this:

```
{
   xtype: 'admingrid',
   ...
   columns: [
      ...
   ],
   store: 'appname.store.administration.User'
}
```

I am loading the store like that:

```
onAfterRender: function() {
    //load all users
    this.setUserStore(this.getUserGrid().getStore());
    this.getUserStore().load();
},
```

and in some cases like this:

```
onAfterRender: function() {
    //load all users
    this.setUserStore(Ext.StoreManager.lookup('appname.store.administration.User'));
    this.getUserStore().load();
},
```

all my my pages extends my Base view and so I thought I just do something like this:

```
Ext.define("appname.view.Base", {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    ui: 'basepanel',

    padding: 15,
    contentPaddingProperty: 'padding',

    listeners: {
        beforedestroy: function() {
            Ext.StoreManager.each(function (item, index, len) {
                 item.clearFilter(true); // param: suppressEvent
                 item.clearGrouping();
                 item.clearListeners(); // this will also remove managed listeners                                  
            });
        }
    }   
});
```

this will cause that the grid is sometimes empty when I am entering the view the first time... I don't understand why.. when I am entering the view the second or sometimes the third time it does show the grid with the entries..

Is there a common way to accomplish such a thing? What I am doing wrong? I don't understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the store if it's present in your afterrender event. That way, you'll re-use the store and just clear it.

So in your afterrender, use StoreManager to lookup the store. If its present, it's been created before and you can clear it.

```
var store = Ext.StoreManager.lookup('storeid');
if(store) {
  store.clearFilter(true); 
  store.clearGrouping();
}
```

This will clear the store whenever it's present.

Comment: i think it doesnt have to do something about my event.. if i remove clearListeners() event, all works fine too.. but what if i got some 'beforeload' events on my store and i want to clear them too.. without knowing what eventhandler are registered.